# Does Visual Studio Express support .NET Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am working for a big organization, but it doesn't want to spend on Visual Studio licences & .NET Framework licences.

Microsoft has released .NET Core which is free & opensource. Now my question is:   does the Visual Studio Express (which is freeware) work on the .NET Core framework (also free & opensource)?

Comment: If you have `less than 250 PCs and less than $1 Million US  in revenue` a total of 5 users can use the Visual studio community edition for free. VS Community edition is pretty much the full VS program.
The express version does no longer exist as before and I think it had the same or close to the same rules as VS-CE.

Comment: You mean < $1M surely?

Comment: Yes, I just copied it from the page and didn't think ;P

Comment: Microsoft also released Visual Studio Code as open source. You probably don't even need a full feature IDE but a code editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). It fully supports .NET Core development.

Be aware, you can use the Community edition only if you have less than 250 PCs and less than $1 million in annual revenues. Up to 5 of your individual users can use the software concurrently to develop and test your applications.

> If you are an enterprise, your employees and contractors may not use the software to develop or test your applications, except for open source, Visual Studio extensions, and education purposes as permitted above. An “enterprise” is any organization and its affiliates who collectively have either (a) more than 250 PCs or users or (b) one million U.S. dollars (or the equivalent in other currencies) in annual revenues, and “affiliates” means those entities that control (via majority ownership), are controlled by, or are under common control with an organization.

See the usage rights [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mlt553321/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can use VS community edition 2017, even it supports .net core

Comment: You should clarify the prerequesites in regards to the company size for using VS Community. See Jite's comment.